Why do these two bash commands behave differently?
I have a bash script which runs the following:
if ! (colima status 2>&1 | grep -Fqe 'colima is running'); then
    colima start
fi

It is running colima start when it should not, if I change it to the following:
colima status 2>&1 | grep -Fqe 'colima is running' || colima start
then the script behaves as expected, and colima start is not run when it should not be.
However, I thought the two forms should behave identically? Why am I wrong?
There are multiple places where I'd like to use this pattern: (if ! (command | with | pipe); then ...; fi), and not all of them convert so easily to a one liner with an || so I'd really to understand.
Bash version is absolutely stuck at 3.2.57 for this script, sadly.
I have set set -xeuo pipefail to try and fail-fast when errors occur.
The whole script takes this form:
#!/bin/bash

function main() {
set -xeuo pipefail
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin/:/sbin/:/usr/bin/:/usr/sbin/:$PATH"

# snip... a bunch of commands that do not fail, and do not modify any env-vars

if ! colima status 2>&1 | grep -Fqe 'colima is running'; then
    colima start
fi

}
main

I call the script like so: ./setup.sh
the output of colima status is this:
time="2024-10-29T21:25:22-04:00" level=info msg="colima is running using macOS Virtualization.Framework"
time="2024-10-29T21:25:22-04:00" level=info msg="arch: x86_64"
time="2024-10-29T21:25:22-04:00" level=info msg="runtime: docker"

I can verify it by modifying the conditional to:
if ! colima status 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | grep -Fqe 'colima is running'; then
I've found that: the grep -Fqe closing the pipe early causes it to get a SIGPIPE which causes the grep to return 141 even when it finds a match.
However having a || at the end apparently prevents this somehow? I don't see why that changes whether a SIGPIPE is sent.

Why are you using parentheses?

so that the status that is negated is that of the whole command

The status that is negated is that of the whole command, even without parentheses.

That's not what parentheses do. Firstly, they're not necessary: ["If the reserved word ‘!’ precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status of the last command in the pipeline ...]". What they actually do is ["force] the shell to create a subshell".

Related question: How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces. For a nice quick reference, see Yola's answer.

Exit status of grep -q is always 0. "Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred." (from man grep)

@user202311 that's not what my grep man page says: Quiet mode: suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a match has been found, making searches potentially less expensive.

It's in the Exit status section.

No it isn't: `EXIT STATUS
The grep utility exits with one of the following values:
 0     One or more lines were selected.
 1     No lines were selected.
 >1    An error occurred.` I think you are assuming a linux grep.


Ahhh, yes. I was looking at the linux man.

The if ... fi code would behave as you describe if colima status exited with non-zero status.  That's because the pipefail setting would cause the status of the grep command to be irrelevant in that case.  There are many pitfalls associated with using pipefail.  See Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail).  However, the ... | ... || ...   code would have the same problem if pipefail is set for it too.  It would be useful to have a full example program (with shebang and set lines) to reproduce your problem.

@pjh I added more info. Including evidence that the colima status command does not give an error status, because if it did, the tee would not run due to pipefail.

Understand what happens in the most basic version first. colima status 2>&1 | grep -Fqe 'colima is running'; echo $? ... what value is echoed at the end? You know 0 is "success" and anything else indicates an error, ight? Good luck.

@shellter yes, I understand the very most basic concepts of how a shell works. This is about why two seemingly equivalent forms do not behave the same.

Whether something receives a SIGPIPE in a situation like this depends on the exact sequence in which certain events happen (i.e. it's a race condition). In particular, whether a program gets a SIGPIPE depends on whether it finishes shoving data into a pipe before the reader on the other end finishes and closes the pipe. ThThisat means it can depend on almost anything, up to and including the phase of the moon. This is one of the reasons pipefail is dangerous.

The problem with pipefail and SIGPIPE is documented in Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail).  If you want to continue using pipefail anyway, one way to avoid the problem in this case is to replace the grep command with grep -Fe 'colima is running' >/dev/null.  That will cause grep to consume all the input before exiting, so a 'SIGPIPE' will not be generated.  The ... | ... || ... also malfunctions due to a SIGPIPE in my testing.  I don't know why it behaves differently for you.

(colima status 2>&1 | grep -Fqe 'colima is running') runs in a subshell because it is in parentheses. I am not sure for your system, but this could be causing the problem because it might return an extra linefeed or some other thing. Try your if block with the parentheses removed and go from there?

Removing the parentheses does not help, sadly.
